# How do i change the number of cuts of a subdivion?

Tags: subdivision-surface

So I created a plane and I subdivided it in 80 cuts to add grass texture. I want to change the cuts to 70 because my laptop is working slow. How can I do that? Where do i find the settings for the subdivion?

Comment: You can't go from 80 to 70 except if you use GeoNodes I guess